# How to get bytes from web page jpeg image without creating another session

Tags: c#, web, jpeg, captcha

Here's the full disclosure: I have full authorization to access one of our company's third-party servicer's websites, from which I download daily reports and perform certain repetitive tasks. I know how to automate IE to perform all of these duties for me, but logging in to the website requires the entry of a captcha phrase, and frankly I'm tired of entering captcha phrases.

When I refresh the page the captcha phrase doesn't change. I isolated the URL for the captcha picture, thinking that I could just (in C#) use a JpegBitmapDecoder to grab a picture of the captcha phrase, crack it (I already wrote some code that will crack it), then navigate to the log in page in IE and put the result in. However, the server considers the JpegBitmapDecoder and my IE page to be different sessions, so it throws a different captcha.

My goal is to find a way to grab the captcha image (it's just a jpeg image) as it appears right off the IE page. I want to do it in such a way that the IE instance doesn't have to be visible (so preferrably no "screencapture" methods). I've tried all sorts of ways using HTML DOM and whatnot but can never get to the raw bytes of the image. I'd prefer not to have to read and decode packets either, if that's even possible. How else can this be done? Certainly the bytes representing the jpeg image are stored locally somewhere.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send session cookie headers with your JpegBitmapDecoder request.

Generally it works like this:

You enter the site. If you don't have session cookie set in browser (`ssid=xxxxxxxxxxxxx`), server sets a new session for you by sending Set-Cookie headers in the response. From now the browser knows what `ssid` it should use, and remembers it. Every new request send to this domain contains `ssid` cookie value that matches the value given by the server first time. So you got to take that `ssid` and tell JpegBitmapDecoder to send request with that `ssid` set.

Comment: That sounds awesome and I'll have to think about it. JpegBitmapDecoder doesn't have a method to tell it to send a request with a certain ssid, and I'll have to dig around on documentation on how to handle cookies in C#. Nonetheless, I'll definitely keep this one on the books.

I'm curious to know the following: when the browser loads the page with the jpeg image, is there a temporary internet file or some representation of the image stored locally on the computer, or just in memory?

Comment: Different browsers keep image in different locations. Chrome additionally compresses it. You said that image does not change when page is refresshed so it has to be keept in session, so if you will use the same sid in bitmap decoder, you will get same image.

Comment: Thanks for your help Flash Thunder. I should have been more specific. The captcha phrase in the jpeg doesn't change, but the background of the jpeg changes. Same phrase just on different backgrounds. So then technically the jpeg actually does change. Does that change the answer of where the image is kept? I can google it, but if so do you know off-hand where IE9 keeps the image?

Comment: It should keep files in `X:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`

Comment: Hm, I don't see that anything was stored for that site in that directory. Thanks for your help, I'll look into some alternative approaches.

Comment: Try subdirectories of that directory.